# HTML canvas game loop

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have a problem implementing a particle system with life time. The problem is that when my particle system run, sometimes it freezes for 1-2 seconds when I try to create the particle life.

I have something like this (all particles have life=2 and end_time=1)

Here's the code: http://jsbin.com/eqexoj/3/

Comment: It would be helpful if you set up a jsFiddle that shows the problem. Why are you redefining all of your functions within your `draw` function?  Why is `main()` not called before `requestAnimFrame()`?

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/BZrqc/` I assume this is what it is suppose to look like??

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to view the code you posted; times out for me.

Most likely thing I'd advise though is to consider garbage collection.

Here's an article I wrote on the subject.
http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/